# Grant access to a EC2 and RDS instances

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm new to AWS and made an instance in the ElasticCloud2 and in the RDS. I'm using Laravel for the project and when I write the URL in the browser, Laravel shows me an error

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect    
to MySQL server on 'ec2-**-***-**-*.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' (111)
```

I know that is has something with the security groups, but I can't understand how to set them up in order to have a communication between the RDS and EC2. Read lots of information about this but still can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: You need to allow your server's security group to access the RDS security group on port 3306. Consult the documentation for instructions.

Comment: Well yeah, but it asks for an IP, while in the RDS instance there is no IP address,only and endpoint

Comment: You can specify security group names in the IP fields in the AWS Console. Start typing the name of your security group (or type `sg`) and it'll give you a list.

Comment: @ceejayoz Well it lists only the EC2 security groups. When I type the RDS security group it says: `Could not update your security group rules (No changes were made): The security group sg-*******' does not exist`

Comment: You should be typing the name of an EC2 security group. You want to edit the RDS's group's security settings to allow the EC2 group access.

Comment: Unfortunately the error remains...

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. This is regarded as noise on Stack Overflow. If your question is closed as unanswerable or did not attract responses, then the first thing to do is to *improve the question*; some guidance for this is [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Low-quality or unanswerable questions will typically be closed, but can be re-opened if improved or clarified (as appropriate).

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the information!